# Addition and multiplication table for field of $5$ elements

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, finite-fields

Can someone help me make a multiplication and addition table for a field $\{0, 1, a, b, c\}$.

I understand the basic rows and columns of $x+0$, $x\cdot 0$, $x\cdot 1$ and that the element plus itself is 0 (so $x+x=0$), but I don't understand how to do the rest. Through logical deduction and making the table symmetrical I think I have the rest but I can't prove it.

**My attempt:**
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
+ & 0 & 1 & a & b & c \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & a & b & c \\
\hline 1 & 1 & 0 & c & a & b \\
\hline a & a & c & 0 & c & b \\
\hline b & b & a & c & 0 & a \\
\hline c & c & b & b & a & 0
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}{l|l|l|l|l|l}
\cdot & 0 & 1 & a & b & c \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 1 & 0 & 1 & a & b & c \\
\hline a & 0 & a & b & c & 1 \\
\hline b & 0 & b & c & 1 & a \\
\hline c & 0 & c & 1 & a & 0
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Why do you think that $x+x=0$ in this field? Are you thinking about addition and multiplication modulo $5$? Personally, I would make life easier by taking $a=1+1$, $b=1+1+1=a+1$, and $c=1+1+1+1=b+1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Next time it's best to write figures in the question text. I've converted your pictures into LaTeX tables using Mathpix Snip automatically for you. Please try it out yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complete Cayley table for a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976768/complete-cayley-table-for-a-field)

Comment: $x + x = 0$ is only true for fields of characteristic $2$, and the only finite fields of characteristic $2$ have $2^k$ elements for some $k$. $5$ is not a power of $2$, so it will not be true of this field. I'm guessing you saw this in some other example (probably the field of 4 elements) and just decided it must be true always, or at least for finite fields. But it isn't. In fact it is rarely true. And you also should have realized it would be a problem that your addition table demands that $c +1 = c+a$. If you add the opposite of $c$ to each, you would get $1 = a$, which cannot be.